# Using fingerprint device in pl/sql by java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use fingerprint device in pl/sql.
I was able to save the fingerprint in Oracle database, now I want to identify this fingerprint.
For this, the manufacturer has provided me with the sdk that I want to use its Java codes.
For this, I wrote a Java code as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.futronic.SDKHelper.*;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Vector;


public class MainForm 
{

    public static String OnGetBaseTemplateComplete(String FPtemplate)
    {
        StringBuffer szMessage = new StringBuffer();
        
        String StrTemplate = FPtemplate;
        byte[] DecodeTemplate = Base64.getDecoder().decode(StrTemplate);
        m_Operation = new FutronicIdentification();
        ((FutronicIdentification) m_Operation).Farn(245);
        ((FutronicIdentification) m_Operation).BaseTemplate(DecodeTemplate);    
        

            Vector<DbRecord> Users = (Vector<DbRecord>)m_OperationObj;
            FtrIdentifyRecord[] rgRecords = new FtrIdentifyRecord[ Users.size() ];
            for( int iUsers = 0; iUsers < Users.size(); iUsers++ )
                rgRecords[iUsers] = Users.get( iUsers ).getFtrIdentifyRecord();

            FtrIdentifyResult result = new FtrIdentifyResult();
            
            int nResult = ((FutronicIdentification)m_Operation).Identification(rgRecords, result);
            if (nResult == FutronicSdkBase.RETCODE_OK)
            {
                szMessage.append("Identification process complete. User: ");
                if( result.m_Index != -1 )
                    szMessage.append(Users.get( result.m_Index ).getUserName() );
                else
                    szMessage.append("not found");
            } else {
                szMessage.append( "Identification failed." );
                szMessage.append( FutronicSdkBase.SdkRetCode2Message( nResult ) );
            }

        
        String StrMessage = szMessage.toString();
        
        return StrMessage;

    }


    /**
     * Contain reference for current operation object
     */
    private FutronicSdkBase m_Operation;
    

    private Object m_OperationObj;       
}
```

But the problem is with functions defined in other Java files and I don't know how to define this binding for PL/SQL.
For example code

```
FtrIdentifyResult result = new FtrIdentifyResult();
```

FtrIdentifyResult itself is a separate Java file that has functions and this function is also defined. FutronicIdentification and Identification and... also.

or in line

```
private FutronicSdkBase m_Operation
```

A variable of type FutronicSdkBase is defined, where FutronicSdkBase is a separate Java file with functions. Now how do I define this for pl/sql?

Comment: Of course, you started with a very simple "Hello World" test to check that you can successfully call Java code from PL/SQL?

Comment: And beware that Java `long` is an integer while Oracle `long` is a string!

Answer (score 1):

You want:

- In Java, `long` is a numeric data-type but in Oracle `LONG` is a (legacy) text data-type; so in the Oracle function you want `NUMBER` not `LONG` as the data-type.
- the final argument and the return type should be `java.lang.String` (note the capital letter) and not `string`.

Like this:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED IdentifyFutronic AS
public class FPIdentifyFutronic {
    public static String FPIdentify(
      long FPtemplate,
      long T1,
      long T2,
      long T3,
      String username
    ) {
        return "Do stuff";
    }
}
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION identify_FP (
  FPtemplate NUMBER,
  T1         NUMBER,
  T2         NUMBER,
  T3         NUMBER,
  username   VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME
    'FPIdentifyFutronic.FPIdentify(
      long,
      long,
      long,
      long,
      java.lang.String
    ) return java.lang.String';
/
```

Then:

```sql
declare
  vOut varchar2(4000);
begin
  vOut := identify_FP(1, 2, 3, 4, 'testjs5');
  dbms_output.put_line(vOut);
end;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Do stuff
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y9gZblnB)